# Generate a link from a word in a string with react-linkify

Tags: reactjs, linkify

Is there a possibility to create a link from a word in a string of text?

Example string:

"This is the first sentence. This is the second sentence."

So the rendered HTML should look like this:

`This is the first sentence. This is the second <a href="https://www.example.com">sentence</a>.`

I want to create a link from the word "sentence" but only the second occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the [linkify-react package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/linkify-react) (not react-linkify, as far as I know) along with the [linkify-plugin-keyword](https://www.npmjs.com/package/linkify-plugin-keyword) package:

```
import Linkify from 'linkify-react';
import registerKeywords from 'linkify-plugin-keyword';

registerKeywords(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])

// ...

<Linkify options={{ formatHref: { keyword: (kw) => `https://example.com/tags/${kw}` } }}>
  Any foo keywords here?
</Linkify>
```